# ImportError: cannot import name 're_path' from 'django.conf.urls'

Tags: python, django

I'm following a Django tutorial and trying to update a `urls.py` file with the following code:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from django.conf.urls import re_path, include


urlpatterns=[
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^',include('EmployeeApp.urls'))
]
```

When I run the server with `python manage.py runserver` I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 're_path' from 'django.conf.urls' (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py)
```

I'm running version 4.0.4 of Django:

```bash
py -m django --version # Prints: 4.0.4
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I needed to change

```py
from django.conf.urls import re_path, include
```

to:

```py
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.urls import re_path
```

Now the error has stopped. ([Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/urls/#re-path))